# how to get a month from list of strings in format of YYYYMM in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of **YYYYMM** formatted strings delimited by comma

```
('202001', '202003', '202012')
```

I would like to convert this into each row in a table.

```
monthNumber
-----------
Month1
Month3
Month12
```

I know how to do for one string and not for a list.

```
select CONCAT('Month', (datepart(month,('200602')+'01'))) as monthNumber.
```

### Updated question:

Is there any way to convert the list of strings into each row in a table? As per **@Gordon Linoff** comment, if it's not supported by SQL SERVER except for `WHERE IN` clause. Any kind of magic in SQL Server to convert the `WHERE IN` clause values to each row in a table?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support anything called a "list" (well, except for the `IN` operator).  Your question is unclear.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Splitting strings has been discussed exhaustively for every version of sql server since 7. Searching will find many examples - pick one. And then you need logic to convert from your current format to your desired format.You seem to have that under control, but note that a desired value of "Month1" is not particularly useful for understanding your goal. We can guess - but we shouldn't need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one is to get the list in a format SQL Server recognizes.  As a single string the example does not properly escape the single-quotes.  If the "list" were a string with escaped single-quotes then you could do something like this

```
declare @list_of_strings            varchar(8000)='(''202001'', ''202003'', ''202012'')';

select concat('Month', cast(substring(ltrim(rtrim(sp.value)), 6, 2) as int)) monthNumber
from string_split(substring(@list_of_strings, 2, len(@list_of_strings)-2), ',') sp;
```

```
monthNumber
Month1
Month3
Month12
```

Comment: Hi, I got `'trim' is not a recognized built-in function name.` error

Comment: It was added in 2017.  Before that 2 functions were used LTRIM(RTRIM(string))

Comment: So, you did set the list as a one string and then convert after to each row. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

first you need to turn that "list" of strings into something usable. how you do this determines on the format of the source data/"list"

one of the easiest ways:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
     VALUES ('202001'), ('202003'), ('202012')
) AS monthInfo(strDate)
```

then to get just month number

```
select CONCAT('Month', (datepart(month,(mi.strDate)+'01'))) as monthNumber
from monthInfo mi
```